# quartz, spring scheduler and spring quartz scheduler synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I am trying to create a synchronous scheduled job, When I implement this with quartz with the *@DisallowConcurrentExecution* annotation the method becomes serialized and with the *org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount* property set to 1 I get only one thread created which is synchronous.

I want to know how we can create a synchronous job using spring scheduler and spring quartz scheduler.

Comment: "I get only one thread created"  <----  Right you set @DisallowConcurrentExecution so you should only be getting one thread.

Comment: Also having only one thread running does not mean it is synchronous.

Comment: Your last line asks how you can create a job to run synchronously after you just finished describing that you have already done it.   So what is it you are asking?

Comment: In spring quartz when I set the threadCount property to 1 and concurrent property to false but I get 2 threads running concurrently. 
Is there something that might override these properties ?